# Order by column using infix operator

Tags: r

It's possibly very simple question, but I couldn't find an answer. I'm trying to apply `abs` on my matrix and then apply `order` by the first column (descending).

In separate rows it looks like:

```
pcaRotaMat <- abs(pcaImportance$rotation)
temp <- pcaRotaMat[order(-pcaRotaMat[,1]),]
```

However, when I'm trying to use the infix operator (`%>%`), I'm getting the following error:

```
t <- pcaImprtance$rotation %>% abs() %>% order(-[,1],)
```

> Error: unexpected '[' in "t <- pcaImprtance$rotation %>% abs() %>% order(["

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable with something more verbose:

```
sort_fn = function(x) { 
    x[order(-x[ ,1]), ] 
}

t <- pcaImprtance$rotation %>% abs() %>% sort_fn
```

Option 2:
If you don't want to create a function to sort:

```
t <- pcaImprtance$rotation %>% abs %>% .[order(-.[, 1]), ]
```

"." is the placeholder here for the matrix. I would also not recommend assigning variables to "t", as this is the function that transposes matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much! your second option is very elegant. I used the `t` just for the question I posted here.. (but thanks for the comment- I won't use it in my questions in order to keep things simple)